# Partitionally resync PTC Integrity Sandbox (exclude Folder)

Tags: mks-integrity

I have an Integrity Sandbox which I checked out without recursing into the subprojects. There are around 30 subprojects and among these one, thats only a big archive of builds.

As I want to use this sandbox regularly by a jenkins job and need to resync the data in the subprojects, I don't want to resnc the whole sandbox.
I want all subprojects but the one named `Archive` and I need this to be done by a cli command.

I already had a look into the reference for `si resync` and the only option that could fit my needs was `--filter`. Unfortunately in the docs, there is only a manual on how to exclude/include files via `--filter=file:<expression>`.

I tried by `si resync -S C:\MySandbox\project.pj --recurse --filter=file:"!Archiv"` but this does not exclude the Archiv folder.

Any hint what I got wrong here? Or another question: is it even possible to exclude directories with the cli?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the version of integrity you use there is a feature called "sandbox scope". The scope for a sandbox can either be set during sandbox creation or be changed for an already given sandbox.

You can use the following command to exclude de desired subproject and then the resync command will ignore this subproject

```
si configuresandbox --scope="!name:Archiv"
```

More info you can find on the  [PTC community](https://community.ptc.com/t5/Integrity-Questions/How-can-I-remove-a-specific-file-from-a-sandbox/td-p/255802)

**Command help**

**Create sanbox**

```
H:\>si createsandbox -?
Usage: si createsandbox options... directory; options are:
    --lineTerminator=[lf|crlf|native|cr]  Line terminator to use in this san
dbox
    --[no]populate  Populate sandbox with members
    -R  Recurse into subsandboxes creation
    --[no|confirm]recurse  Recurse into subsandboxes creation
    --scope=attribute:name[=value]
             memberrevlabellike:<expression>
             anyrevlabellike:<expression>
             name:<expression>
             path:<expression>
             type:text|binary
             any
             subproject:<expression>
    --[no]sparse  Create sparse sandbox
    --[no]openView  Activate sandbox view after completing the command
    --devpath=value  The development path (to refer variant projects)
    --[no]failOnAmbiguousProject  Whether to abort when multiple projects co
rrespond to a flat project string.
    -P value  The name of the target project
    --project=value  The name of the target project
    --projectRevision=value  The project revision (to refer build projects)
    --[no]awaitServer  If server does not respond, keep trying
    -?  Shows the usage for a command
    --[no]batch  Control batch mode (no user interaction in batch mode)
    --cwd=value  Act as if command executed in specified directory
    -F value  Read the selection from a specified file
    --forceConfirm=[yes|no]  Specify an answer to all confirmation questions

    -g  User interaction should happen via the GUI
    --gui  User interaction should happen via the GUI
    --hostname=value  Hostname of server
    -N  Responds to all confirmations with "no"
    --no  Responds to all confirmations with "no"
    --password=value  Credentials (e.g., password) to login with
    --port=value  TCP/IP port number of server
    --quiet  Control status display
    --selectionFile=value  Read the selection from a specified file
    --settingsUI=[gui|default]  Control UI for command options
    --status=[none|gui|gui.actions|default]  Control status display
    --usage  Shows the usage for a command
    --user=value  Username to login to server with
    -Y  Responds to all confirmations with "yes"
    --yes  Responds to all confirmations with "yes"
```

**Change sandbox configuration**

```
H:\>si configuresandbox -?
Usage: si configuresandbox options... sandbox location...; options are:
    --[no]computeChecksums
    --lineTerminator=[lf|crlf|native|cr]  Line terminator to use in this san
dbox
    --scope=attribute:name[=value]
             memberrevlabellike:<expression>
             anyrevlabellike:<expression>
             name:<expression>
             path:<expression>
             type:text|binary
             any
             subproject:<expression>
    --[no]sparse  Make the sandbox sparse
    -?  Shows the usage for a command
    --[no]batch  Control batch mode (no user interaction in batch mode)
    --cwd=value  Act as if command executed in specified directory
    -F value  Read the selection from a specified file
    --forceConfirm=[yes|no]  Specify an answer to all confirmation questions

    -g  User interaction should happen via the GUI
    --gui  User interaction should happen via the GUI
    --hostname=value  Hostname of server
    -N  Responds to all confirmations with "no"
    --no  Responds to all confirmations with "no"
    --password=value  Credentials (e.g., password) to login with
    --port=value  TCP/IP port number of server
    --quiet  Control status display
    --selectionFile=value  Read the selection from a specified file
    --settingsUI=[gui|default]  Control UI for command options
    --status=[none|gui|gui.actions|default]  Control status display
    --usage  Shows the usage for a command
    --user=value  Username to login to server with
    -Y  Responds to all confirmations with "yes"
    --yes  Responds to all confirmations with "yes"
```